# kurento renegotiation issue between java and c++ webrtc

Tags: java, c++, webrtc, kurento, sdp

I'm using java kurento and generating offer like:

```
WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEndpoint =  new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(pipeline).recvonly().build();
String kmsOffer = webRtcEndpoint.generateOffer();
sendToNativeWebrtcOffer( kmsOffer  ).
```

On webrtc c++ side I got error:

```
No video codecs supported.
(peer_connection.cc:5920): Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='video0'. (INVALID_PARAMETER)
 (peer_connection.cc:3019): Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='video0'.
Failed to set remote description: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='video0'.
```

On webrtc c++ side I have (where we got offer from kms and can't generate answer because of error):

- UnifiedPlan
- h264 track
- audio track

Next sdp works ('test sdp'. I think we need to find difference)...it is firefox

```
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-78.0.2 4798395224003580427 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 DA:16:67:31:17:45:9E:53:64:F9:94:40:3C:BC:21:A1:E0:55:13:18:60:49:E7:67:F4:E8:0C:59:A9:0B:3B:1E
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=recvonly
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:71d1f805a8a27e5c6193e4fac0de651a
a=ice-ufrag:60f11fb1
a=mid:0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:2095406925 cname:{3c31b223-b584-453f-8f56-16695b7a5081}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 121 126 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=recvonly
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;x-google-start-bitrate=10000;x-google-max-bitrate=20000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;x-google-start-bitrate=10000;x-google-max-bitrate=20000
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=ice-pwd:71d1f805a8a27e5c6193e4fac0de651a
a=ice-ufrag:60f11fb1
a=mid:1
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:955534267 cname:{3c31b223-b584-453f-8f56-16695b7a5081}
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:71d1f805a8a27e5c6193e4fac0de651a
a=ice-ufrag:60f11fb1
a=mid:2
a=setup:actpass
a=sctp-port:5000
```

Next is kurento (The goal is fix this sdp somehow...) and don't works with error above:

```
: v=0
o=- 3812873843 3812873843 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=Kurento Media Server
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio0 video0
m=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 0
a=setup:actpass
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=recvonly
a=mid:audio0
a=ssrc:410140273 cname:user559063493@host-1de13827
a=ice-ufrag:ibt+
a=ice-pwd:mhNBi9HkI3DiZvAenuwEjR
a=fingerprint:sha-256 16:E8:64:59:79:F7:50:47:B5:00:BD:01:FF:59:F1:BA:7B:2E:35:4F:BC:61:90:B5:57:13:0C:3F:20:B8:F8:E3
m=video 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 101
a=setup:actpass
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=recvonly
a=mid:video0
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:101 nack
a=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:101 ccm fir
a=ssrc:2873701790 cname:user559063493@host-1de13827 
a=ice-ufrag:ibt+
a=ice-pwd:mhNBi9HkI3DiZvAenuwEjR
a=fingerprint:sha-256 16:E8:64:59:79:F7:50:4
```

Comment: I found difference: the error disappear when I added to kurento sdp line:
```
a=fmtp
``` 
The question now...how to configure endPoint properly to get this field from createOffer

Comment: Kurento does not specify a H264 profile-level-id (which is kind of a dialect for h264). This isn't valid.

Comment: Is it means I can't establish connection from inside kurento for receive and send h264?

Comment: Is it real to establish video connection by webRtcEndpoint.generateOffer()?

Comment: it means you need to find out what kind of h264 kurento expects to send or receive and then fix this in the kurento code

Comment: Do you mean source code? Looks like...i need more deep explanation...

Comment: I absolutely no have idea what should i do...